# How to create a tree array from a flat array of objects, then number each tree node's level and sort nodes at each level?

Tags: javascript

**Note: Solution below!**

**The Problem:**
I needed code to turn a flat array of objects with id and parent values into a tree. The number of levels deep is unknown, since the flat array is generated dynamically.

Also, once the items are in a tree, I needed nodes to be assigned a level property value, depending on what tree level they're on (root nodes = level 0, the root's immediate child nodes = level 1, children's children = level 2, etc).

Finally, nodes at each tree level should be alpha sorted by their id. So root ids should be sorted, then the roots children, then the children's children, etc etc.

I found some solutions that met at least two of my requirements, but none that met all three.

**Solution:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DavidACondit/wtb40y1u/)

```
var x = [
{id: 10, parent: 0, children: []},
{id: 20, parent: 10, children: []},
{id: 30, parent: 10, children: []},
{id: 40, parent: 30, children: []},
{id: 50, parent: 30, children: []},
{id: 60, parent: 30, children: []},
{id: 70, parent: 20, children: []},
{id: 80, parent: 20, children: []},
{id: 90, parent: 40, children: []},
{id: 100, parent: 40, children: []}, 
{id: 95, parent: 40, children: []},
{id: 110, parent: 50, children: []}, 
{id: 120, parent: 60, children: []}, 
{id: 130, parent: 0, children: []},
{id: 140, parent: 130, children: []},
{id: 150, parent: 140, children: []},
{id: 160, parent: 140, children: []},
{id: 170, parent: 140, children: []},
{id: 180, parent: 160, children: []},
{id: 190, parent: 160, children: []},
{id: 200, parent: 190, children: []} 
];
```

Into this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>10
            <ul>
                <li>20
                    <ul>
                        <li>70</li>
                        <li>80</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>30
                    <ul>
                        <li>40
                            <ul>
                                <li>90</li>
                                <li>95</li>
                                <li>100</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>50
                            <ul>
                                <li>110</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>60
                            <ul>
                                <li>120</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>130
            <ul>
                <li>140
                    <ul>
                        <li>150</li>
                        <li>160
                            <ul>
                                <li>180</li>
                                <li>190
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>200</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>170</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**In case my fiddle ever disappears, here's my complete solution:**

```
<html>

<script>
window.onload = function () {

// STEP 1: Get a flat array of objects.

/* A flat (1 dimensional) array, which can later be turned into a tree, since each array item has an id and parent property. */
var x = [
{id: 10, parent: 0, children: []}, // 2 immediate children, root node
{id: 20, parent: 10, children: []}, // 2 immediate children
{id: 30, parent: 10, children: []}, // 3 immediate children
{id: 40, parent: 30, children: []}, // 3 immediate children
{id: 50, parent: 30, children: []}, // 1 immediate children
{id: 60, parent: 30, children: []}, // 1 immediate children
{id: 70, parent: 20, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 80, parent: 20, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 90, parent: 40, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 100, parent: 40, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 95, parent: 40, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 110, parent: 50, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 120, parent: 60, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 130, parent: 0, children: []}, // 1 immediate children, root node
{id: 140, parent: 130, children: []}, // 3 immediate children
{id: 150, parent: 140, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 160, parent: 140, children: []}, // 2 immediate children
{id: 170, parent: 140, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 180, parent: 160, children: []}, // 0 immediate children
{id: 190, parent: 160, children: []}, // 1 immediate children
{id: 200, parent: 190, children: []} // 0 immediate children; 5 levels deep (level = 4, since start level is 0)
];


// STEP 2: Turn the flat array into a tree (hierarchical) array.

function tierData (arr) {
/* 
    Params: 
        @arr = flat array. Each array item is an object containing id, parent, and children properties.

    Description: 
        Takes a flat array and turns into into a tree (hierarchical) array.
*/
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr.forEach(function (n) {
            if (n.parent === arr[i].id) {
                arr[i].children.push(n);
            }           
        });
    }
    return arr.filter(function (n) { return n.parent === 0 }); // Only return root nodes and their children, children's children, etc.
}

var td = tierData(x);
//console.log(td);


// STEP 3: Assign a "level" property to each tree level. Numeric sort tree items for each level in the tree.

function treeSortAndLevel (treeArr,flatArr,flatIndex) {
/* 
    Params: 
        @treeArr = A tree (hierarchical) array, created from a flat array using the tierData fn.
        @flatArr = A flat array on which @treeArr is based.
        @flatIndex = DON'T PASS AN ARG. This is assigned a value by subsequent recursive fn calls. 

    Description: 
        Returns a tree which is numeric sorted at each level and each tree node is assigned a level property value, starting with root node(s) level = 0.
*/
    // If not provided (ie the fn's first call), create an indexer for the flat array.
    if (flatIndex === undefined) {
        var flatIndex = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < flatArr.length; i++) {
            flatIndex[flatArr[i].id] = flatArr[i];      
        }   
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < treeArr.length; i++) {
        // Numeric sort the current treeArr tier (ie array) by id.
        treeArr.sort(function (a, b) { return a.id - b.id; });
        // Determine and set the treeArr item's level.
        var parentId = treeArr[i].parent;
        var level = 0;
        while (parentId !== 0) {
            level++;
            var ancestor;
            ancestor = flatIndex[parentId];
            parentId = ancestor.parent;
        }
        treeArr[i].level = level;
        treeSortAndLevel(treeArr[i].children,flatArr,flatIndex);
    }
    return treeArr;
}

var sortedAndLeveldTree = treeSortAndLevel(td,x);

console.log(sortedAndLeveldTree);


// STEP 4: Append a multi-tiered unordered list to the DOM for the sorted and level numbered tree.

function printTree (treeArr) {
/* 
    Params:
        @treeArr = A tree (hierarchical) array, created from a flat array using the tierData fn.

    Description: 
        Prints a tree to the console. 
*/
    for (var i = 0; i < treeArr.length; i++) {  
        var indent = '';
        var level = treeArr[i].level;
        while (level > 0) {
            indent += '  --  ';
            level--;
        }
        console.log(indent + treeArr[i].id);    
        printTree(treeArr[i].children);
    }
}

function createTreeDOM (treeArr, ul) {
/* 
    Params:
        @treeArr = A tree (hierarchical) array, created from a flat array using the tierData fn.
        @ul = DON'T PASS AN ARG. This is assigned a value by subsequent recursive fn calls.

    Description: 
        Returns an unordered list tree (DOM element).
*/
    if (ul === undefined) {
        ul = document.createElement('ul');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < treeArr.length; i++) {  
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var tx = document.createTextNode(treeArr[i].id);
        li.appendChild(tx);
        if (treeArr[i].children.length > 0) {
            var subUL = document.createElement('ul');
            li.appendChild(subUL);
            createTreeDOM(treeArr[i].children, subUL);
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    return ul;
}

// Alternatively, print the sorted and level numbered tree to the console in a tree-like style using the printTree fn:
//printTree(sortedAndLeveldTree);

var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = 'The below tree was dynamically created from a flat array of objects using JS. Tree items (the objects, not the DOM elements) are assigned a level property, starting with 0 for root items. Tree items are sorted by their id at each tier (tree level).';
document.body.appendChild(p);

var treeDOM = createTreeDOM(sortedAndLeveldTree);
document.body.appendChild(treeDOM);

}
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build the tree object first and then render the wanted html structure.

for getting sorted result, I suggest to sort the data in advance with using a two level approach by sorting `parent` first and then by `id`.

To return a wanted level, you could add a `level` variable to `getTree` and initalize with zero if not set.

The increment this value for every deeper level.

```js
function getTree(array, level) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    level = level || 0;
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a.id + ' level: ' + level));
        Array.isArray(a.children) && li.appendChild(getTree(a.children, level + 1));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    return ul;
}

var data = [{ id: 10, parent: 0 }, { id: 20, parent: 10 }, { id: 30, parent: 10 }, { id: 40, parent: 30 }, { id: 50, parent: 30 }, { id: 60, parent: 30 }, { id: 70, parent: 20 }, { id: 80, parent: 20 }, { id: 90, parent: 40 }, { id: 100, parent: 40 }, { id: 95, parent: 40 }, { id: 110, parent: 50 }, { id: 120, parent: 60 }, { id: 130, parent: 0 }, { id: 140, parent: 130 }, { id: 150, parent: 140 }, { id: 160, parent: 140 }, { id: 170, parent: 140 }, { id: 180, parent: 160 }, { id: 190, parent: 160 }, { id: 200, parent: 190 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [],
            o = {};

        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = a;
            if (a.parent === root) {
                r.push(a);
            } else {
                o[a.parent] = o[a.parent] || {};
                o[a.parent].children = o[a.parent].children || [];
                o[a.parent].children.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.parent - b.parent || a.id- b.id; }), 0);

document.body.appendChild(getTree(tree));
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nina. I like your approach and I've never seen a "guard operator" used before (I had to google how you're using && for value assignment and to determine if a function should be executed). Your code is missing two requirements, though. 1)  All nodes must be alpha sorted at each level. Under the 40 node, it should be 90, 95, and 100 child nodes. 2) Though I didn't show it in my DOM result, I want each node to be assigned a level property value equal to its position in the tree.

Comment: btw, your sort is not by alpha, but on numerical value, becuase alpha sorts `'100' < '90' < '95', but you need to treat the values as number (what they are).

Comment: Good catch on the sort error. I updated my answer and jsfiddle.