# How do I set one array element as root node of tree array structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `a = [1,2,3]` and array 'b' which is a tree-structured array like described in the image:

[image: 'b' array]

Now I want to make "1" from the array 'a' as the root node of array 'b'

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) { 
  array[i].children=[]; 
} //debugger; 
function tree (array) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    array.forEach(function (n) { 
      if (n.PARENT === array[i].POSID) { 
        array[i].children.push(n); 
      } 
    });
  } 
  return array.filter(function (n) { return n.PARENT === "" ;}); 
} 
var fdata = tree(array);
```

The output should be something like below:

[image: output array]

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried ?

Comment: Please show us the structure of `b` **as code**, not just as a picture. It's not clear what that structure is currently. Also not sure what *"Now I want to make "1" from the array 'a' as the root node of array 'b'"* means...?

Comment: Can you also show the code for your tree?

Comment: I have tried below code to convert a flat array to tree-structure:for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
 {
  
  array[i].children=[];
 }
//debugger;


function tree (array) {

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array.forEach(function (n) {
            if (n.PARENT === array[i].POSID) {
                array[i].children.push(n);
    
            }    
   
        });
    }
    return array.filter(function (n) { return n.PARENT === "" ;}); 
}
var fdata = tree(array);  .......I want to make this whole tree structure as children of some array element say "1".

Comment: For example, see this thread for reference:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315718/how-to-create-a-tree-array-from-a-flat-array-of-objects-then-number-each-tree-n?rq=1...In the above way I could convert flat array to tree-array.Now final step is to attach this tree array to some array element say "1" or "teja".